# Swift UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not working

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have got a table in my Swift project like this

```
var tableView: UITableView! 
tableView = UITableView()
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension       
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postTexts.count
    }      
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 250;
   }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 5
   }
```

I wanted my tableview's height to be automatic thus i used
 `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`,but it is still showing nearly half of the cells width

[image]

Comment: @RajeshkumarR how do i change cell's height then?

Comment: "I wanted my tableview's height" did you mean cells height? I'd suggest to add a screenshot of what's the output that you got.

Comment: @AhmadF i did add image

Comment: You have set wrong Constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You need intrinsic cell size for this to work. Delete `heightForRowAt` entirely. Your constraints in your cell should determine the cell size, this means your constraints should be at least pinned from top and bottom. Add the following code after setting the `rowHeight`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
```

Answer (score 1):

You must delete the `-heightForRow` method and set on the table view an `estimatedRowHeight`.
The `estimatedRowHeight` is used to calculate the bar size etc of the TV, so it should be a real value closest as possible to an average size of the table view cell height.
Now, if you are using auto layout and constraints are set correctly you should see a correct resize of your `UITableViewCell`. To set correctly the constraints inside the TVC you should think to place them in a way that they can control the size of your cell.
For instance say that your TVC has just one label and that label has 4 constraints attached to its superview: top, bottom, trailing and leading with a fixed constant size. The `UILabel` instance has also the numberOfLines set to 0 (means that it can expand to fill all your text).
When the autolayout engine starts to request the label intrinsicContentSize, the label will return a value that will fit all your text, the superview size will change the size according to that.
If you fix the TVC to a specific height as you did before, the TVC can't expand itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with constraints so here is what i did.
First i added heightForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Then i created a variable

```
let tableViewHeight  = postTexts.count*100
```

And put that in my height constraint

```
    tableView.anchor(PostsDiv.bottomAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0,heightConstant: CGFloat(tableViewHeight))
```

And it works pretty well for me

Comment: You are setting the tableview height equal to the amount of cells * the height of those cells? It might work but it's not the right way

Comment: @Hapeki Why not?

Comment: One of the reasons is that cells probably won't get dequeued and your tableView height is going to cause huge issues. 

Example: Your postTexts.count is 400. Your tableview height will be 400*100, which will result in terrible, terrible, terrible performance. This is working entirely against the best practices for your tableView.

Comment: @Hapeki but i couldn't find any other solution

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're using anchors? I'd recommend interface builder so you get to learn the concept of constraints visually before you do it programmatically. Apple recommends interface builder to begin with. I can show you a simple demo If you are planning on using interface builder.

Comment: @Hapeki I did start with storyboard,but i prefer programmatical approach

Comment: I can understand that, I had the same preference but now I switched back to xib/nib. It's very important you know the theory behind AutoLayout and how it works before you make it yourself more difficult by using the programmatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Pin the view's constraints to the superview's edges. Also call the estimatedRowHeight.. Remember to call a reload from the table to invoke height calculation for each cell to display.