# Show all cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got this table in my swift project

```
tableView = UITableView()
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
let tableViewHeight  = postTexts.count*200
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 55
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.allowsSelection = false;
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 55
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell  = UITableViewCell()
    let ProfilePicture = UIImageView()
    ProfilePicture.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cole")

    let username  = UILabel()
    username.text = posters[indexPath.row]
    username.numberOfLines = 0

    let postText = UITextView()
    postText.text = postTexts[indexPath.row]
    postText.isScrollEnabled = false
    postText.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    let border = UIView()
    border.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 17, g: 221, b: 219)

    cell.addSubview(ProfilePicture)
    cell.addSubview(username)
    cell.addSubview(postText)
    cell.addSubview(border)

    ProfilePicture.anchor(cell.topAnchor, left:cell.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 14, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 50,heightConstant:50)
    username.anchor(cell.topAnchor, left:ProfilePicture.rightAnchor, bottom: postText.topAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 13, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0)
    postText.anchor(username.bottomAnchor, left:ProfilePicture.rightAnchor, bottom:nil, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0)
    border.anchor(postText.bottomAnchor, left:cell.leftAnchor, bottom: cell.bottomAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0,heightConstant:1)
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.sizeToFit()
    return cell
}
```

I want my table to show all cells,but it only shows half of them like here[image]

As you see he only shows 2 cells even though there are 4 of them,how can i change it's behaviour to show all cells?
Here are my table constraints

```
tableView.anchor(PostsDiv.bottomAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 15, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 15, widthConstant: 0,heightConstant:tableView.contentSize.height+tableView.contentInset.bottom+tableView.contentInset.top)
```

Comment: Hi Bruno Snickers- The problem is in estimatedHeightForRowAt  method .Please return height greater than 100 .May be you are retrning wrong cell heght check it then load table It would be working fine.

Comment: @DEVENDRAAGNIHOTRI I returned 300,still the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970655/swift-uitableviewautomaticdimension-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This is still the same issue from your older posts. Your cells aren't working correctly since you want automatic height in cells but you have the  wrong constraints set on your tableView and cell. This is a third repost of your question but here is your answer from Andrea and me:

[Swift UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970655/swift-uitableviewautomaticdimension-is-not-working)

Comment: I have uploaded all constraints can you tell me which one is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I created nearly the same UI using interface builder.

https://github.com/Hapeki/Example4

I recommend you take a look at this and how AutoLayout works before settings stuff programmatically. The UI is based on my explanation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42971009/6414904

Demo video:

[image: demo]

The cells are automatically sized, seen by the large lorem ipsum text. If you want to make the entire screen scroll you should consider making a headerView for your tableView, but that's out of the scope for this question. In your code you set the tableView height based on the count of your cells * height: `let tableViewHeight  = postTexts.count*200`
, thats is the wrong way to work and it will cause issues after issues. I would highly recommend using interface builder (Storyboards) or if you want some "hybrid" approach you could go for xibs/nibs, where you can make View classes that contain outlets and do some programmatic stuff in it.